# What software to use to send (OI) commands to Create 2. Using windows laptop and supplied Create 2 cable?

Tags: irobot-create, serial

I read most of the iRobot Create 2 Open Interface (OI). It says send these serial commands to the Create 2 to get it to do the described action, but no suggestion of what software to use to send these serial commands through the USB interface.  I did install the FTDI Drivers to enable the USB to serial connection.  Question: What serial software should I use to communicate with Create 2?  Is there a tool to verify that the supplied usb to serial cable supplied with Create 2 is functioning and if the Create 2 is functioning? (I did a reset on Create 2 using Spot and Dock buttons)

Comment: We have a few question about this already, the bottom line is that the commands are binary and thus your software should support that. If in doubt, write your own.

Answer (score 0):

Any serial port terminal emulator program should let you read the spew when the robot is reset.  This will verify the cable (at least the RX path).  Hyperterminal used to be a good one on Windows.  Realterm and Putty are also good.

To verify the TX path of the cable, you can send the BELL character (ASCII code 7) which will reset the robot.  I think most emulators should let you send this with CTRL-G.  Unfortunately, this is the only command you can send to the robot from a terminal emulator.  To send any more commands, you need send commands programmatically.

Comment: PuTTy shows the data stream and CTRL-G does a reset.